# does setrlimit limits memory allocation in kernel space?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

By the RLIMIT_AS in setrlimit, we can limit the maximum size of the process's virtual memory in bytes. But when a user space program calls a system call, and the system call kmalloc memory in kernel,  is the memory accounted for setrlimit?

Comment: I suspect not, but I don't know how to prove it. I wouldn't expect kernel memory allocations to be charged to a specific process. They also shouldn't be long-lived.